# Using retrofit requests and response for doing specific function

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to send a request to server and when i get response from server I want to change the phone from silent mode into normal mode. I'm using retrofit and I'm new at all of this.

Here is how I make request and process response:

```
 Call<ServerResponse3> response3 = requestInterface.chec(ProfileFragment.Global.email);
 response3.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse3>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse3> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse3> response3) {
        ServerResponse3 resp = response3.body();

        Toast.makeText(BService.this, resp.getResult(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(BService.this, ProfileFragment.Global.ID, LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (resp.getResult().contains("true")) {
            //Normal Mode Programatically
            mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        } else {
            //Silent Mode Programatically
            mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
}
```

And here is the interface part:

```
@GET("project5/web/normal")
Call<ServerResponse3> chec (@Query("email") String email);
```

So am I doing this right or there is something wrong?

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati cannot resolve getSystemService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use activity name for context like this:

```
final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) YourActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```